# Convert from string to any basic type

Tags: c#

I have a `string` and a `Type`, and I want to return the `string` value converted to that `Type`.

```
public static object StringToType(string value, Type propertyType)
{
    return Convert.ChangeType(value, propertyType, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
}
```

This returns an `object` that I can use in a property set value call:

```
public static void SetBasicPropertyValueFromString(object target,
                                                   string propName,
                                                   string value)   
{
  PropertyInfo prop = target.GetType().GetProperty(propName);
  object converted = StringToType(value, prop.PropertyType);
  prop.SetValue(target, converted, null);
}
```

This works for most basic types, except nullables.

```
[TestMethod]
public void IntTest()
{ //working
    Assert.AreEqual(1, ValueHelper.StringToType("1", typeof (int)));
    Assert.AreEqual(123, ValueHelper.StringToType("123", typeof (int)));
}

[TestMethod]
public void NullableIntTest()
{ //not working
    Assert.AreEqual(1, ValueHelper.StringToType("1", typeof (int?)));
    Assert.AreEqual(123, ValueHelper.StringToType("123", typeof (int?)));
    Assert.AreEqual(null, ValueHelper.StringToType(null, typeof (int?)));
}
```

`NullableIntTest` fails on first line with:

> System.InvalidCastException: Invalid cast from 'System.String' to 'System.Nullable`1[[System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]'.

I'm having difficulty detemining if the type is nullable and changing the behaiour of the `StringToType` method.

Behaviour I am after:

If string is null or empty, return null, else convert as per the non-nullable type.

**Result**

Like Kirill's answer, only with one `ChangeType` call.

```
public static object StringToType(string value, Type propertyType)
{
    var underlyingType = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(propertyType);
    if (underlyingType != null)
    {
        //an underlying nullable type, so the type is nullable
        //apply logic for null or empty test
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(value)) return null;
    }
    return Convert.ChangeType(value,
                              underlyingType ?? propertyType,
                              CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
}
```

Comment: You can make your method generic: `public static object StringToType<T>(string value) where T : struct` ...

Comment: @KarelFrajtak Na, because of the way it's called, see second code fragment. `prop.PropertyType` is from reflection, so is not known until runtime.

Comment: Your `if` check isn't quite right.  Your special cases shouldn't be for *any* generic type, it should be *just* for a `Nullable<T>` because they are boxed differently.

Comment: Ok, but it can be an option too;)

Comment: @Servy Yes I have updated. Now based on Kirill's answer.

Comment: @KarelFrajtak Well, no, it can't as it doesn't compile. Try it, if you can get it to work, post as answer and I'll upvote it.

Comment: @weston there is a bug, `Assert.AreEqual(string.Empty, ValueHelper.StringToType(string.Empty, typeof (string)));`

Comment: @johnny5 I'm not a c# dev anymore, this is so old, best ask a new question.

Comment: @weston sorry I should have been more clear,  there is a bug in this code I've posted an answer below incase anyone is using this in production

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot use Convert.ChangeType on nullable types cause it is not inherited from IConvertible. You should rewrite your method.

```
public static object StringToType(string value, Type propertyType)
{
   var underlyingType = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(propertyType);
   if(underlyingType == null)
          return Convert.ChangeType(value, propertyType,  CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
   return String.IsNullOrEmpty(value)
          ? null
          : Convert.ChangeType(value, underlyingType, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
}
```

Comment: there is a bug in this code.  This code could be used in a generic situation,  meaning someone could be using the code to to convert the string value to string.  While if the string is empty you return null instead of empty

Comment: this code has no bug. requirements was: "If string is null or empty, return null, else convert as per the non-nullable type". This code behave as required.

Comment: For enum types, it throws an InvalidCastException, and an additional condition is needed, as answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20835906), for example.

Answer (score 3):

```
public static object StringToType(string value, Type propertyType)
{
   var underlyingType = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(propertyType);
   return underlyingType == null ? Convert.ChangeType(value, propertyType, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) : Convert.ChangeType(value, underlyingType, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
}
```

Comment: Good, just missing logic for handling null or empty strings.

Comment: you wrote a good explanation Servy
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13381751/1173331)

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
prop.IsGenericType && Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(prop) == value.GetType()
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that the return value of `ChangeType`, as well as your method, is `object`.  When you box any nullable type into an `object` it doesn't box the nullable type.  If the value, at runtime, is actually null it boxes a `null`, and if it has a value it boxes the actual underlying value (rather than the nullable version).

```
int? i = 5;
object o = i;
Type t = o.GetType();//will be `int`, not `Nullable<int>`
```

This won't happen in the general case with any other type; `Nullable<T>` has special compiler support to do this.  You'll basically need to special case `Nullable` in your code as well; If your method is passed a `Nullable` type you'll need to first check the object for `null`, and if not  `null`, use the underlying type of the `Nullable` instead.

Answer (score 1):

The code with help of Kirill Bestemyanov' snippet:

```
public static object StringToType<T>(string value)
{
   return StringToType(value, typeof(T));
}

public static object StringToType(string value, Type propertyType)
{
   var underlyingType = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(propertyType);
   if(underlyingType == null)
     return Convert.ChangeType(value, propertyType, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
   return String.IsNullOrEmpty(value)
     ? null
     : Convert.ChangeType(value, underlyingType, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
}
```

And usage (`WL` just writes to console). You were right, the generic method can't use `int?` as generic parameter.

```
WL(StringToType("1", typeof (int?))); // -> 1
WL(StringToType<int>("1"));           // -> 1
WL(StringToType<int?>("1"));          // error, not compilable
WL(StringToType<Nullable<int>>("1")); // -> 1
```

Comment: what I was saying is that you cant use it like this with reflection, see my SetBasicPropertyValueFromString method for how it must be used.

Comment: You're right, but in test you are not using the way you describe. One method is useful in the code and the other in tests. I'm not telling you have to do it my way, I'm just extending your idea.

Answer (score 0):

You must use an appropriate cast method for each type you want to support.

```
int parsedInt;
int.TryParse("1", out parsedInt);

double parsedDouble;
double.TryParse("0.0d", out parsedDouble);
```

It is impossible for the compiler to figure out the type depending on the contents of the string. See the following links for more information about converting from string to scalars types: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397679.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384043.aspx.

Comment: Sure that would be impossible, but I'm not asking the compiler to work out the type. I have the target type in `Type propertyType`