# Convert.ChangeType How to convert from String to Enum

Tags: c#, enums, converters

```
  public static T Convert<T>(String value)
  {
    return (T)Convert.ChangeType(value, typeof(T));
  }

   public enum Category 
   {
       Empty,
       Name,
       City,
       Country
   }

  Category cat=Convert<Category>("1");//Name=1
```

When I call `Convert.ChangeType`, the system throws an exception on the impossibility of conversion from String to Category.
How to do the conversion?
Maybe I need to implement any converter for my type?

Comment: `Enum.Parse(typeof(Category), "City", true);`

Answer (score 89, accepted):

Use [Enum.Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/essfb559%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method for this.

```
public static T Convert<T>(String value)
{
    if (typeof(T).IsEnum)
       return (T)Enum.Parse(typeof(T), value);

    return (T)Convert.ChangeType(value, typeof(T));
}
```

Comment: Wow! This is a great addition.

Comment: `(T)Enum.Parse(typeof(T), value, true); // Ignore case: true.`

Answer (score 13):

.Net Core version :

```
public static T Convert<T>(string value)
{
    if (typeof(T).GetTypeInfo().IsEnum)
        return (T)Enum.Parse(typeof(T), value);

    return (T)System.Convert.ChangeType(value, typeof(T));
}
```

Comment: `(T)Enum.Parse(typeof(T), value, true) // Ignore case: true.`