# C#: Converting strings to enum and non-enum with the same function

Tags: c#, types, enums, casting, converters

I have this line of code:

```
obj.Properties.ToList().ForEach(p => parameters.Add(Convert.ChangeType(p, ctor.GetParameters()[parameters.Count].ParameterType)));
```

`obj.Properties` is a string array (`string[]`), and `parameters` is a list of objects (`List<object>`). I would like to create a new instance of a class, for which I've selected a constructor (`ctor`), which has as many parameters as many strings in my `obj.Properties` array are.

In order to Invoke the constructor, I need to cast the strings to types, which the constructor needs (as you can see my try above). This works for `int` and `bool`, but the constructor also has an `enum` parameter, and when my code tries to convert the string to an enum, I get `InvalidCastException`.

I read a SOF [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20835880/convert-changetype-how-to-convert-from-string-to-enum), in which Enum.Parse is suggested instead, but I would like to do this in one line (doesn't depend on if it is an enum or not). So I used the solution of the linked answer:

```
public static T MyConvert<T>(String value)
{
    if (typeof(T).IsEnum)
    return (T)Enum.Parse(typeof(T), value);

    return (T)Convert.ChangeType(value, typeof(T));
}
```

And then:

```
obj.Properties.ToList().ForEach(p => parameters.Add(MyConvert< ctor.GetParameters()[parameters.Count].ParameterType>(p)));
```

But I got an error: `Operator '<' cannot be applied to operands of type 'method group' and 'Type'`

I also tried

```
Type type = ctor.GetParameters()[parameters.Count].ParameterType;
obj.Properties.ToList().ForEach(p => parameters.Add(MyConvert<type>(p)));
```

But I got: `'type' is a variable but is used like a type`

This is a working solution:

```
obj.Properties.ToList().ForEach(p =>
{
    if (ctor.GetParameters()[parameters.Count].ParameterType.IsEnum)
    {
        parameters.Add(Enum.Parse(ctor.GetParameters()[parameters.Count].ParameterType, p));
    }
    else
    {
        parameters.Add(Convert.ChangeType(p, ctor.GetParameters()[parameters.Count].ParameterType));
    }
});
```

**But is there any way to use the same code for enums and non-enums? So, I'm looking for a solution without `if(...IsEnum)` in the ForEach.**

Comment: Can you show how you invoke the constructor?

Comment: @MatteoUmili ctor.Invoke(parameters.ToArray())

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution: making the MyConvert function non-generic (so that knowing the exact type is enough in run time, instead of in compile time).

```
public static object MyConvert(String value, Type T)
{
    if (T.IsEnum)
        return Enum.Parse(T, value, true);

    return Convert.ChangeType(value, T);
}
```

And then:

```
obj.Properties.ToList().ForEach(p => parameters.Add(Parse(p, ctor.GetParameters()[parameters.Count].ParameterType)));
```